# Cannot configure PHP built-in server in PhpStorm

Tags: php, macos, phpstorm

I am following JetBrains' official instructions on setting up the built-in server [HERE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/php-built-in-web-server.html)

I am currently on the "Enabling a built-in Web server" section:

1. Download PHP 5.4.0 or higher.

Done! There is now a folder on my desktop named "php-7.1.4", untouched since download, now for number 2: "Configure the downloaded PHP interpreter in PhpStorm" ([HERE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/configuring-local-php-interpreters.html))

I am stuck on 4.2, when I select the directory of the folder on my desktop, nothing happens. It does not "display the version of the PHP engine detected in the specified folder", as per the instructions. It simply continues to say PHP is not installed.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After abandoning the built-in server in favour of MAMP, I have found the solution. The download from php.net seems to be all kinds of messed up.

My solution is to download MAMP and use the php executable it provides (MAMP/bin/php/php[version]/bin/php), but then just continue without using the MAMP server.

Works fine!